A question about non-abelian simple group
Suppose that $G$ is a non-abelian simple group and $H$ is a soluble subgroup of $G$ of prime-power index $p^k$, $k\geq 1$. Then $H$ is a Hall $p'$-subgroup of $G$ and a maximal subgroup of $G$.
The former conclusion is obvious, the latter is not known why?
This question came from a paper's -- On $\sigma$-Solubility Criteria for Finite Groups --Lemma 2.2.
